# Print part of the screen

Tags: java

is it possible to print part of the screen around the mouse?
I try with :

```
Toolkit tool = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
Dimension d = tool.getScreenSize(); 
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(d);
Robot robot = new Robot();
File f = new File("screenshot.jpg");
BufferedImage img = robot.createScreenCapture(rect);
ImageIO.write(img,"jpeg",f);
```

but it prints all screen, i can see that i can set the size of rectangle but i don't see how can i center rectangle so that it be around mouse.

Comment: How much area around mouse you want to print?

Comment: I don't know maybe 300 x 300, it doesn't really meter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static BufferedImage printScrAroundCursor(int width, int height)
{
    Toolkit tool = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    Robot robot = new Robot();

    PointerInfo a = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
    Point b = a.getLocation();
    int x = (int) b.getX();
    int y = (int) b.getY();

    int topLeftX = Math.max(0, x - (width / 2));
    int topLeftY = Math.max(0, y - (height / 2));
    if (topLeftX + width > tool.getScreenSize().getWidth())
        width = tool.getScreenSize().getWidth() - topLeftX;
    if (topLeftX + width > tool.getScreenSize().getHeight())
        width = tool.getScreenSize().getHeight() - topLeftY;
    return robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(topLeftX , topLeftY , width, height));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`MouseInfo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/MouseInfo.html) to get the mouse's location. From there, it's simple midpoint math:

```
int width = ...;
int height = ...;
Point m = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(m.x - width / 2, m.y - height / 2, width, height);
Robot robot = new Robot();
File f = new File("screenshot.jpg");
BufferedImage img = robot.createScreenCapture(rect);
ImageIO.write(img, "jpeg" ,f);
```

You will probably encounter strange results if the mouse is too close to the edge of the screen, but without more information, this special behavior is up to you to define how you wish for it to be.

Answer (score 0):

```
Point mousePos = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
int width = 300;
int height = 300;
Point origin = new Point(mousePos.getX() - width / 2, mousePos.getY() - height / 2);
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(origin.getX(), origin.getY(), width, height);
BufferedImage img = robot.createScreenCapture(rect);
```